# When is the slice element covered in this code?

Tags: go

I logged every element before I appending it. But the result looks like that some element is covered.

I do not know when it is covered.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    graph := [][]int{
        []int{3, 1},
        []int{4, 6, 7, 2, 5},
        []int{4, 6, 3},
        []int{6, 4},
        []int{7, 6, 5},
        []int{6},
        []int{7},
        []int{},
    }

    fmt.Println(allPathsSourceTarget(graph))
}

func allPathsSourceTarget(graph [][]int) [][]int {
    n := len(graph) - 1
    result := make([][]int, 0, 200)

    var pathRecord func(target, path []int)
    pathRecord = func(target, path []int) {
        if (len(target) == 0) && (path[len(path)-1] == n) {
            fmt.Println("insert into", path) // should end with 7
            result = append(result, path)
        }

        for _, v := range target {
            pathRecord(graph[v], append(path, v))
        }
    }

    for _, v := range graph[0] {
        pathRecord(graph[v], []int{0, v})
    }

    return result
}
```

Every element in the result should end with 7.

Comment: What's the output you currently received, and what's the expected?

Comment: output:
`[
[0 3 6 7],
[0 3 4 5],
[0 3 4 6 7],
[0 3 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 4 5],
[0 1 4 6 7],
[0 1 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 6 7],
[0 1 7],
[0 1 2 4 7],
[0 1 2 4 6 7],
[0 1 2 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 2 6 7],
[0 1 2 3 6 7],
[0 1 2 3 4 5],
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6],
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 5 6 7],
]
`
what I excepted is:
`[
[0 3 6 7],
[0 3 4 7],
[0 3 4 6 7],
[0 3 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 4 7],
[0 1 4 6 7],
[0 1 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 6 7],
[0 1 7],
[0 1 2 4 7],
[0 1 2 4 6 7],
[0 1 2 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 2 6 7],
[0 1 2 3 6 7],
[0 1 2 3 4 7],
[0 1 2 3 4 6 7],
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7],
[0 1 5 6 7],
]`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't' understand what you are trying to do. What each ints list in the graph represents?

Comment: the problem is probably something to do with slice and append, trying to figure it out

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a leetcode problem solution(but wrong), you can see it [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/). Slice `graph[i]`  represents all nodes where node `i` can reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is with this line:

```
pathRecord(graph[v], append(path, v))
```

Go is so "smart" so he's trying to reuse the same slice allocated memory and you actually change the path you already added to result. ):

try this instead:

```
newPath = make([]int, len(path))
copy(newPath, path)
pathRecord(graph[v], append(newPath, v))
```

Comment: Indeed it is! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.  I assume it's weirdness with append and slices

I assume that the memory backing "this append" is passed into the recursive function as the slice is acting something like a pointer

Then the next time it's the same memory so it gets overwritten

So you need to take a copy at each recursion to stop it overwriting

```
pathRecord = func(target, path []int) {
    if (len(target) == 0) && (path[len(path)-1] == n) {
        var c []int = make([]int, len(path))
        copy(c, path)
        //fmt.Println("insert into", payload) // should end with 7
        result = append(result, c)
    }

    for _, v := range target {
        pathRecord(graph[v], append(path, v)) //this append
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem really happened on append, this is a good solution. Thanks!